# Trouble Centering 2 floated Divs when screen size is reduced

Tags: css, html, center

I have written the follow code [centering floated divs](http://jsfiddle.net/mrmwood/95v39/)

```
<body>
<div class="educationContainer">
    <div class="employmentOuter">
        <div class="employmentInner">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    test
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <div class="picture">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="picture">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when you make the screen small enough to float on the 2 divs to place one on top of the other is triggered, they are both left aligned. the test text is still centered.

How can I make them float on top of each other but still be centered.

it may need to be done outside of a table, but this is where I ended up after hours of try.

any help would be great and a more streamlined code would help me learn.

Comment: When something is floated, the only way you can center it is by changing the margin (which is calculated exactly by pixel), otherwise it always floats to left or right (can't make it center)

Answer (score 0):

I updated this so you can see one way to do it with spans.

http://jsfiddle.net/95v39/2/

I removed the table and changed the picture divs to spans with an inline-block display

```
<body>
    <div class="educationContainer">
        <div class="employmentOuter">
            <div class="employmentInner">
                <div class="employmentHeader">
                    test
                </div>
                <span class="picture">
                </span>
                <span class="picture blue">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```